# How to Save Credential or AcquireTokenSilentAsync from Azure Directory on React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, azure-active-directory

I try this great library https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-azure-ad#user-content-getcredentials-adcredentials to Login in My React Native App for Azure AD , the login is work great but when the app is close i need to relogin again, so i guess i need to add method to save credential or AcquireSilenceTokenAsync. But the problem is there is no lot information that i can use to make that happen .  i tried to getAccesToken in ComponentWillMount so when the token is exist the displayType state will be 'after_login' and the app will render after_login screen, but it seem it didnt work.

```
constructor(props) {
       super(props)

       this.state = {
          info : null,
          shouldLogout : false,
          displayType : 'before_login'

       };
     };
componentWillMount(){
  let displayType;
  let check_credential = ADContext.checkCredential('https://graph.microsoft.com')
  if(this.props.access_token == null)
  {
    displayType : 'before_login'
  }
  this.setState({displayType});
}
```

so anyone has implemented azure ad on react native can help me here ? should i cache the token or something or save credential maybe?

Comment: The method may have already been in the document:https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-azure-ad#savecredentialsdataadcredentialspromise

Comment: you mean use this saveCredentials(data:ADCredentials):Promise ? im just recently learn react js so i dont realy understand how to implement it , so i decide to save the token to Asyncstorage and when the user press logout it will remove the token from asyncstorage